# Link two select boxes using angular js

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I want to link two select boxes , with change in one will change other.

Following is my code

```
{
  "Maths": [
    {
      "code": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "sex": "M"
    }
  ],
  "English": [
    {
      "code": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "sex": "M"
    },
    {
      "code": "John1",
      "lastName": "Doe1",
      "sex": "M1"
    },
    {
      "code": "John"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the given code first dropdown should show only -English,Maths while other will show -lastName based on item chosen, 
so if English is chosen in select box-1 then select box-2 option key= John1,value-Doe1.

```
<select id="select_language" ng-model="myColor" ng-options="id  for (id, person) in test"> </select> 
<select id="select_dialect" ></select>
```

In addition to this i would like to have
In the second dropdown we are populating the values in select box label. I also need to add option values which is related to code.
So this would result in something like this

```
<select id="select_dialect" ng-model="myColor1" ng-options="item.sex for item in myColor" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="John">M</option>
<option value="John1">M1</option>
<option value="John2"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the ng-options to the `selected_language`:

```
  <select id="select_language" ng-model="selectedLanguage" ng-options="id  for (id, person) in data"></select>
  <select id="select_dialect" ng-model="selectedLastName" ng-options="item.lastName for item in selectedLanguage"></select>
```

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/p4fwOUfoBpLRFAvYxdBh?p=preview) is the working plunker

**Update**

You can use `track by` to specify the value of the options:

```
<select id="select_sex" ng-model="selectedSex" ng-options="item.sex for item in selectedLanguage track by item.code"></select>
```

I have updated the plunker too.

**Update II**

Here you have two options. You can set the selected value in the controller:

```
$scope.selectedLanguage = $scope.data["English"];
```

or you add the following to the select tag:

```
ng-init="selectedLanguage = data['English']"
```

I have updated my plunker

Comment: Thanks @boindiil .. It has been really helpful !! :)
I have 1 more question related to it . please find it above

Comment: Thanks @boindiil.. !! Thanks for your help !! I have one more question to ask  .. i hope you won't mind :) .. I just realised i need to set the default value of the first select box to "English".. My mistake i just skip it earlier..=

Comment: I think i have also mentioned that with English in the first box , i want to have John selected . For this i have added this but it didn't work -

<select id="select_sex" ng-model="selectedSex" ng-init="selectedSex =  data['English']['M']"
    ng-options="item.sex for item in selectedLanguage track by item.code"></select>

Can you please help !!

Comment: Here is the plunker with all default values: http://plnkr.co/edit/dDW66KYSEn8S5CpMchJe?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<select id="select_language" ng-model="myColor" ng-options="id for (id, person) in selectData"></select>
<select id="select_dialect" ng-model="myPerson" ng-options="person.lastName for person in myColor"></select>
```