# Link two select in AngularJS with JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

So, i tried with this [Link two select boxes using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255074/link-two-select-boxes-using-angular-js), but don't know how to use this formula in my case with this JSON:

```
{
    "option1": [{
        "countries": [
            {
                "currency": "ARS"   
            },
            {
                "currency": "USD"  
            }
        ]
    }],
    "option2": [{
        "countries": [
            {
                "currency": "EUR"   
            },
            {
                "currency": "GBP"  
            }
        ]
    }],
    "option3": [{
        "countries": [
            {
                "currency": "RU"   
            },
            {
                "currency": "TR"  
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

The first select should have option1, option2, option3. And if option1 is selected, the second select should have ARS and USD.

What is the proper way to do this?

**UPDATE1:** i did something similar like @Joaozito Polo answered, but tried to set the default values with ngModel in both selects and when i change the first select, the second get blank.

**UPDATE2:** now i get it and is working, buuuuuuut.... only in [the jsbin](https://jsbin.com/diqamiyaja/1/edit?html,js,output), i don't understand why isn't working in my real code. When i do:

```
<select ng-options="value as name for (name, value) in options" ng-model="currentOption" ng-change="showSomething()"></select>
```

and in ngChange do a console log like this:

```
$scope.showSomething = function() {
    console.log($scope.currentOption);
};
```

I get the same option all the time, but in jsbin the option change :/ i am working with ionic and cordova, maybe is a bug?

**UPDATE3:** found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416716/2012904), working perfect right know. Is this a good solution? why with ionic doesn't work? i wan't to understand this behavior.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Maybe you were close...

Comment: Did you need to define your array as an object?

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/i1xvfyuLl3odctXO3veR?p=preview

Comment: the proper way to ask is to show what you tried that isn't working

Comment: sorry, i updated the answer now.

Comment: well... The difference on my jsbin and your code, is with you did repeat the "option1" name three times... I used "option1", "option2" and "option 3"... could be this typo?

Comment: No Joaozito, that is just an example, in my code i didn't repeat the "option1"

Answer (score 1):

Considering your data model, as is, as a variable "options"...

You need to use (key, value) on ng-options:

```
Option
<select ng-options="value as name for (name, value) in options" ng-model="currentOption"></select>

Currency
<select ng-options="item as item.currency for item in currentOption[0].countries" ng-model="currency"></select>
```

look at this jsbin: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/jipome/edit?html,js,output)